# Rails - how to merge two objects and keep only duplications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, activerecord, merge

```
scope1 = User.where(:last_name => 'green')
scope2 = User.where(:last_name => 'mayer')
merged_scope = scope1.merge(scope2)
```

In **merged_scope** will be users with last name **green** and **mayer**. But let's suppose a following scenario:

```
scope1
-
peter green
mark green
joe green
```

and

```
scope2
-
caleb mayer
mark mayer
caroline mayer
```

and I am trying to get into **merged_scope** only records with the same **first_name**. Speaking about this specific case, then in **merged_scope** would be:

```
 mark green
 mark mayer
```

How to do something like this?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

This is a simplified example, the query is more complex and I need them generate separately (in the example above it can be generated in one query).

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way but my first thought is...

```
scope0 = User.where(last_name: 'green')
scope2 = User.where(last_name: 'mayer', first_name: scope0.map(&:first_name))
scope1 = User.where(last_name: 'green', first_name: scope2.map(&:first_mame))
merged_scope = scope1.merge(scope2)
```

extract all 'green'
map all first_name columns from the 'green' scope
extract all 'mayer' where first name is in the first_name array from the first scope, 
extract all 'green' (again) this time where firs tname is in the first_name array from the second scope.

Result is two scopes, one for 'mayer' one for 'green' where first names of records in each scope must exist as first naemes in the other scope

Answer (score 1):

You could try this little tricky query:

```
last_names = ["green", "mayer"]
User.joins("INNER JOIN users another ON another.last_name != users.last_name 
            AND users.first_name = another.first_name").
     where(last_name: last_names, another: { last_name: last_names })
```